Sublime: delete mail list from 2 files from differents folders
I have txt files with a mail list (master) in differents folders and another file with mail address to be deleted in master file from differents folders.
I used Shift+ctrl+F to delete individual adresss mails. I add differents folders to delete individual mails address, this work fine.
But the list to delete is large and I wonder if its possible use the txt file with email address to delete.
Regards
Rodrigo
